# Use union with find

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search in columns B,C,G only , I used below code:

```
Set findName = shWaseet.Range("B:C","G:G").Find(Me.SearchBox.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
```

and it take only B & C columns,
I try

```
Set findName = shWaseet.Range("B1:C" & irow, "G1:G" & irow).Find(Me.SearchBox.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
```

and it didn't work,
I know I have to use UNION, but I don't know how to use it with find, I tried:

```
Dim ran As Range
Set ran = Union(Range("B:C"), Range("G:G"))
Set findName = shWaseet.Range(ran).Find(Me.SearchBox.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
```

and it throw an error, also I tried:

```
Set findName = shWaseet.Union(Range("B:C"), Range("G:G")).Find(Me.SearchBox.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
```

and nothing.
how to achieve that?

Comment: What error? what line? `R.Find` works where `R` is set to `Union(Range("B:C",Range("G:G"))`. Your problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: ran is Range, so Range(ran) is wrong. modify to: Set findName = ran.Find(Me.SearchBox.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart).   Hope the code is in the sheet where "B:C" and "G:G" belongs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using the Find Method With a Discontinued Range

**The Objects**

- There are 3 major objects in Excel:

  - Workbook
  - Worksheet
  - Range
- Each range has a worksheet and each worksheet has a workbook.
- If you e.g. use `Range("A1")` then this range is not qualified i.e. it is a range on the active sheet which may or may not be a worksheet and which may or may not be the correct worksheet (talking about `Union(Range("B:C"), Range("G:G"))`).
- Similarly, if you e.g. use `Worksheets("Sheet1")` then the worksheet is not qualified i.e. it is a worksheet in the active workbook which may or may not be the correct workbook.

**The Variables**

- Once you start using variables for each object, you will spare yourself many headaches.

  ```
  Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' note the 'wb' 
  Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("B:C,G:G") ' note the 'ws', or...
  Set rg = Union(ws.Range("B:C"), ws.Range("G:G")) ' note the 'ws', or...
  Set rg = Union(ws.Columns("B:C"), ws.Columns("G")) ' note the 'ws'
  ```
- Applied to you particular case, the simplest would be:

  ```
  Dim rg As Range: Set rg = shWaseet.Range("B:C,G:G") ' note the 'shWaseet'
  ```

  a single string with comma-separated addresses with less than 256 characters.

**The Find Method**

- The `Find` method will fail if the worksheet is filtered.
- If you need to find values in hidden rows or columns, you need to set the `LookIn` parameter to `xlFormulas`.
- The `Find` method has 9 arguments, the first 7 being of great importance (plenty to learn).
- What will happen when you use the `Find` method with your range `"B:C,G:G"`?

  - Depending on the value of the `SearchOrder` parameter, e.g. if it is `xlByRows`, it will start the search with cell `C1` (not `B1`) and go down `B2,C2,B3,C3,...` until it reaches `C1048576` after which it will continue the search with `G1` to `G1048576` and finally, it will look into cell `B1`. Basically, by default, it starts with the 2nd cell and ends with the 1st cell.
  - To avoid this peculiar behavior, you would want to set the parameter of the `After` argument to the last cell of the range.

**The Last Cell**

- The last cell of your range is cell `G1048576`. To set it dynamically, you can use:

  ```
  Dim lCell As Range
  With shWaseet.Range("B:C,G:G")
      With .Areas(.Areas.Count)
          Set lCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
      End With 
  End With
  ```
- If you don't expect the resulting cell to be the first cell of the range, you can ignore this last cell business as I have in the continuation.

**The Solution**

```vb
Dim sValue As Variant: sValue = Me.SearchBox.Value

Dim rg As Range: Set rg = shWaseet.Range("B:C,G:G")
' Omitting the 'After' argument i.e. not expecting the result in 'B1'
Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = rg.Find(What:=sValue, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
If fCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Could not find """ & sValue & """.", vbCritical
    Exit sub ' ?
End If

' Continue
MsgBox "Found """ & fCell.Value & """ in """ & fCell.Address(0, 0) & """.", _
    vbInformation
```

Comment: thanks @Vbasic2008, and how to loop all the cells in the range to find all the cells contain sValue ?

Comment: That's out of the scope of the question. Ask another one. In this case, you could use a combination of the `Find` and `FindNext` methods. A basic example is on Microsoft's FindNext page but you can put `[vba] FindNext` into the search box above and it will surely open a page with dozens of links.

Answer (score 1):

[image: try to find the qwerty]

'try to find the qwerty

```
Sub example()
   Dim findName As Range
   Set findName = Union(Range("B:C"), Range("G:G")).Find("qwerty", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
   Debug.Print findName.Address
End Sub
```